# unable to execute gradle - Illegal option: D

Tags: gradle

I'm getting stuck to find the root cause why I'm unable to run gradle. I'm using gradle 4.9 running on my OS Centos 7. it worked perfectly before, I'm not sure why it doesn't work anymore.
anybody please help me

```
> gradle -version
Illegal option: D
Try `jar --help' for more information.
```

I also tried reinstalled gradle with gradle v5.1.2, error messages are different

```
 > gradle -version
Illegal option: X
Try `jar --help' for more information.
```

My Java version is 11.0.7

Comment: Have you changed any properties files or environment variables? Like `gradle.properties`?

Comment: Hi @madhead I don't find any gradle.properties. I used sdk to install gradle. should I create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

after spending couple hours to resolve the issue,turns out my java is the root cause.
I identified when I tried to execute jar file with java -jar, I got an error invalid option: X. 
however when I run java --version, it displays jar 11.0.2.

it seems to be alternatives command I used when installing java.

I solved the issue by reinstalling java with yum and set the environment variable and PATH. now, gradle command can be executed